# Sheep It not launching

Tags: windows, sheepit

I have downloaded the newest version of Sheep It from the website, but when I launch the exe file (Im on Windows) it says "Extracting __%", and when it finishes extracting it closes and does not do anything. If I go into Task Manager, I see "SheepIt Renderfarm client wrapper" as a background process.
How do I fix this? I have a 64-bit OS.

Comment: Questions about external utilites aren't likely to be answered here, however I assume you've seen the very bottom answer on the FAQ page of the web site at [https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/faq.php](https://www.sheepit-renderfarm.com/faq.php) ?

Comment: I havent, actually, thanks a lot

Comment: @JohnEason I don't have that folder

Comment: Can't help in that case. I've never used Sheepit. Try asking on that web site.

Comment: Thanks anyways and have a happy new year!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help further. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on all 3 of my machines.

This is the solution I found; all you have to do is delete the config file located at C:\Users should be called (.sheepit.config). Then it should launch normally.

Comment: First of all, having that file in C:\Users is absurd, as that is the folder that stores all users, so you don't generally put anything into it. Second of all, I don't have that file at all... and yes I have searched for it.

Comment: @HighElfWisard Rather oddly, I just read your post and agree that it is absurd. However I've just found it in C:\users. Well actually - in my useraccount, but not in a subfolder of it.  Bizarre! No sarcasm intended btw.

Comment: It's 100% empty except for User account folders for me. Might be due to me uninstalling it, as I have found a good solution: Google Colab.